# Graphics glitches with JPanel's custom drawing with JButtons

Tags: java, swing, drawing

I have a JPanel that implements custom drawing to draw a background. Over this, the application can place JButtons to detect clicks on certain areas of the JPanel. However, when highlighting the (non-opaque) buttons with the mouse, the underlying JPanel's graphics become all glitchy.

[image: My game]

These are 9 JPanels with the custom drawing, each of them with 2 filling JButtons (R and L). The top right block and the ones looking like it are 'fresh'. The bottom right has both buttons highlighted, the middle one only the 'R', etc.

I create my buttons like this:

```
rotatePanel = new JPanel();
        rotatePanel.setOpaque(false);
        GridLayout rotateLayout = new GridLayout(1, 2);
        rotatePanel.setLayout(rotateLayout);

        rotateRight = new JButton("R");
        rotateRight.addActionListener(this);
        rotateRight.setOpaque(false);
        rotateRight.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        rotateRight.setBorderPainted(false);
        rotatePanel.add(rotateRight);

        rotateLeft = new JButton("L");
        rotateLeft.addActionListener(this);
        rotateLeft.setOpaque(false);
        rotateLeft.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        rotateLeft.setBorderPainted(false);
        rotatePanel.add(rotateLeft);
```

and this is my drawing code:

```
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Rectangle clipRect = g.getClipBounds();
    clipRect.grow(-4, -4);

    int thirdWidth = clipRect.width/3;
    int thirdHeight = clipRect.height/3;
    for (int x = 0; x < Board.DIM; x++) {
        //Draw the columns
        for (int y = 0; y < Board.DIM; y++) {
            //Draw the rows
            g.drawRect(thirdWidth * x, thirdHeight * y, thirdWidth, thirdHeight);
        }
    }

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, clipRect.width, clipRect.height);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changes to a child component require part of your panel to be redrawn, only the area overlapped by that component needs to be drawn. When you do `g.getClipBounds()`, you are getting the region to be painted, not the bounds of your whole panel. You probably just want to use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`.

Comment: Ah, of course. Now i also learnt something new about java painting ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but adding an ActionListener to the button that forces a redraw of the panel seems to help:

```
rotateLeft.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        rotatePanel.repaint(); // rotatePanel must be final to be used here
    }

});
```

As long as I hold the button the lines are not visible but when the actionListener is fired then the lines are redrawn.

You could also use a MouseListener for the rotateLeft button that forces a redraw of the components on the events mousePressed, mouseReleased and mouseClicked. Then the lines should be also visible when holding the mouse button down.

Comment: This works, but is kind of a hacky method; The problem with my code is that he repaints in the incorrect area, your fix is to redraw in the correct area afterwards instead of just not drawing in the wrong one in the first place :)